JPA many to one query retrieves too many fields
I have the same model on Java JPA:
@Entity
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "review")
public class Review {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private User user;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "game_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Game game;

    @Column(name = "review_text", length = 1000)
    private String review_text;

    @Column(name = "summary")
    private String summary;

    @Column(name = "likes")
    private Integer likes;

    @Column(name = "rating")
    private Integer rating;

    @Column(name = "createdAt")
    @CreationTimestamp
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date createdAt;

And I've done this endpoint:
@GetMapping("/ofgame/{gameId}")
public List<Review> getReviewsByGame(@PathVariable Integer gameId) {
    List<Review> reviews = new ArrayList<>();
    if (this.gameRepository.findById(gameId).isPresent()) {
        reviews = this.reviewRepository.findAllByGameId(gameId);
    }
    return reviews;
}

Being the method of the repository the next one:
List<Review> findAllByGameId(Integer gameId);

But my problem is that the query is returning all the fields from Game and User (including encoded passwords) when I thought only the user_id and game_id were going to be returned.
Did I understood something wrong about the JPA mapping? Or there is simply something I didn't add?

Why you expecting only those fields?

Why is this behavior a problem?  You call out encoded passwords specifically, but how about just not presenting those to users?

In any case, yes, you seem to have a serious misunderstanding of relationship mapping.  By mapping an entity relationship, you provide for the entities on one end to navigate directly to the entity(-ies) on the other end.  This is among the hallmarks of ORM.  Depending on how you do it, that can go both ways.  If that's not what you want then map the foreign key as an ordinary field instead of using it to map a relationship, but be aware that that will apply to all uses of your entity, not just the use you're looking at now.

I thought that by using referencedColumnName = "id" I was going to get only that field and in fact when I see my table on the DB, the rows only show the ids from the foreign fields. Is it correct then to retrieve all the users and games associated to a review and having to take their id one by one? It seems heavy

I finally got it, it was primarly because a misunderstanding of the JPA mapping but what it finally was a solution was creating a DTO (Data Transfer Object) with the exact fields I wanted and then change the custom query.
DTO for my Review entity:
@Getter
public class ReviewDTO {
    private Integer id;
    private Integer userId;
    private Integer gameId;
    private String review_text;
    private String summary;
    private Integer likes;
    private Integer rating;
    private Date createdAt;

    public ReviewDTO(Integer id, Integer userId, Integer gameId, String reviewText, String summary, Integer likes, Integer rating, Date createdAt) {
        this.id = id;
        this.userId = userId;
        this.gameId = gameId;
        this.review_text = reviewText;
        this.summary = summary;
        this.likes = likes;
        this.rating = rating;
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
    }
}

Review repository with new query:
@Repository
public interface ReviewRepository extends JpaRepository<Review, Integer> {
    @Query("SELECT new com.lobby.app.model.ReviewDTO(r.id, r.user.id, r.game.id, r.review_text, r.summary, r.likes, r.rating, r.createdAt) " +
            "FROM Review r WHERE r.game.id = :gameId")
    List<ReviewDTO> findReviewsByGameId(@Param("gameId") Integer gameId);
}

